# Do I need reputation points in Stack Overflow to post in Meta?

Tags: support, reputation

I know:

- That I can post in Meta (obviously)
- That I have 1 point in Meta (as of 03:41 29-11-2016)
- That I have more points in SO
- That I don't remember being automatically congratulated by SO with a new privilege to post questions in MSO

So... I wanted to ask if I would have needed X reputation points in SO to post questions in MSO, did I? If so, how many?

Comment: You might not remember, but you did get a notification when you got the privilege: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q3jI.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need 5 reputation on Stack Overflow to post on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). This is listed on the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta).

However, you posted here to [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), which is not the same as [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Meta Stack Exchange reputation is completely separate and works just like a regular “main” site such as SO — there's no “post to meta” privilege to be earned to post to Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: There is a ["participate in meta"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) privilege on MSE, earned at 5 rep. Its only purpose is to confuse people.

Comment: @Laurel Maaaaayyybe it can be made useful by requiring 5 rep to ask a question tagged with [meta](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta).

Answer (score 0):

At 45 rep on Stack Overflow you already have enough reputation (5) to post in Meta Stack Overflow.

You can find the rep needed to post there at https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta